# El parámetro `uri` pasado a `openUri()` es undefined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente código para conectar una base de datos con mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, "Error connecting to MongoDB"));


db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Connected to Database :: MongoDB');
});


module.exports = db;
```

Pero cuando lo ejecuto recibe el siguiente error:

> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined".

Éste es el stack completo del error:

```
C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
          ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
    at C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:351:10
    at C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1149:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\config\db.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\a19a73210\desktop\animetube\index.js:14:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
```

¿Por qué me sigue diciendo que es undefined? He intentado de todo pero da el mismo error.

Comment: Hola Hideaki, he editado tu pregunta para que se ajuste mejor al formato y contenido del sitio. Es importante que las preguntas pidiendo ayuda con depuración (o todas las preguntas en general) tengan: un título descriptivo, un resumen breve de lo que se quiere hacer y el problema, lo que se ha intentado (poner "lo he intentado todo" no vale), y el código mínimo para reproducir el problema. Siguiendo ese patrón es más fácil obtener ayuda y tus preguntas serán más útiles para otros usuarios (a la hora de responder o si itenen el mismo problema). Revisa el [tour] y lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error ocurre porque el valor de `process.env.MB` es `undefined`. Por eso da el error de que la URI/URL de la base de datos no está definida.

Depura el código hasta ahí y asegurarte de que sí viene la URL de conexión en esa variable.